# How I can search for all public objects Facebook Graph Search API?

Tags: facebook, search, graph

Facebook stopped providing hashtag searches with API
And now  I am using facebook Graph Search API and want to get public post such as comments, status updates who are having conversation about an object eg #Dolphin
Is it possible? How?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer possible, because public post search has been deprecated with Graph API v2.0.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> - Public Post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)